# How to find installed plugins

Tags: plugins

I been searching long of any way to find the list of the plugins installed in a WordPress site. Though I got a way, the "http-wp-plugins.nse" brute force script but I don't know how to use this script.

If any body know any way please share.

Answer (score 2):

On the admin side, which I assume is where you want to run this, the [`get_plugins`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L215) function will retrieve an array of plugins along with data about each.

```
function dump_plugins() {
  var_dump(get_plugins());
}
add_action('admin_init','dump_plugins');
```

Obviously, that code is illustrative only. It will make a big mess of your site.